# A problem in elementary combinatorial space geometry.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Also asked on overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296567/some-elementary-schubert-calculus-calculations/296583#296583

Consider $3$ dimensional projective space (although you don't have to know anything specific, just that there is no parallelism.)
Here is the question:

How many pairs of intersecting lines in space are there such that:

1) Their plane passes through a given fixed line $l$.

2) Their point of intersection lies on a given plane $P$.

3) Together they intersect $4$ given lines $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4$ ?

The answer in the book listed is $17$, assuming there is no typo.
The following is useful.

$\bf{Theorem}$ Given four lines in space, there are $2$ lines intersecting all four.

${\bf Thoughts :}$
Well, you don't have to read this if you want to approach the question fresh, but I can tell you where my problem lies, so you get the core quicker.

First, either one of the lines intersects $3$ of $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4$, or each line intersects $2$ of them.

In the first case there are $\binom{4}{3}=4$ many triples of lines from $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4$, say $l_1,l_2,l_3$, and together with $l$ there are two lines intersecting all four. Each of these intersects $P$ is a point. Now all that is needed is a line through this point and the lines $l$ and $l_4$, this is unique as is easy to see. This gives $2\times 4=8$ line pairs.

In the second case each line must intersect $2$ of the lines $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4$.
There are $\frac{1}{2}\binom{4}{2}=3$ many ways to divide this. Now if the book is right for each such division there must be $3$ solutions. This is were I cannot proceed further.

Comment: Now there is a related question on MathOverflow: [Some Elementary Schubert Calculus Calculations](https://mathoverflow.net/q/296567).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I posted it, since there seemed no interest in the question here.

Comment: Yes I've added a link because it is recommended that each post should be linked to other copies if a question is cross-posted, see meta: [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5085#5088). (The questions are not exactly the same, but still I thought that adding the link might be useful.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yeah, the other answer has received an answer, I was thinking of deleting this one. Dont know if that is bad form or not.

Comment: There is a post on meta: [What to do with my cross-posted question that got answered elsewhere?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27641) The suggestion there is to self-answer the question if it got satisfactory answer on another site. This might also earn you [self-learner badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) :-)

Comment: My personal opinion is that it a judgement called and it should be decided on case-by-case basis. If there were already some useful comments to the topic of the question or some partial answer, I would be definitely in favor of keeping this copy of the question, too. Since there was nothing like that, basically the only question is whether the copy on this site still can be useful. (For example, it might appear if somebody is searching for something similar. Or people following these tags might learn something useful.)